# How to create 3D Tag Cloud in Java

Tags: java, swing

I need a suggestion/idea how to create a 3D Tag Cloud in Java (Swing)
(exactly like shown here: http://www.adesblog.com/2008/08/27/wp-cumulus-plugin/)
, could you help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go either with Swing and Java2D or OpenGL (JOGL).

I used OpenGL few times and drawing text is easy using JOGL's extenstions (TextRenderer).

If you choose Swing, than the hard part will be implementation of a 3D transformation. You'd have to write some sort of particle system. The particles would have to reside on a 3D sphere. You personally would be responsible of doing any 3D transformation, but using orthogonal projection that would be trivial. So it's a nice exercise - what You need is here: [Wiki's spherical coord sys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) and here [3d to 2d projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection).

After You made all of the transformation only drawing is left. And Java2D and Swing have very convenient API for this. It would boil down to pick font size and draw text at given coordinates. Custom JPanel with overriden `paintComponent` method would be enough to start and finish.

As for the second choice the hardest part is OpenGL API itself. It's procedural so if You're familiar mostly with Java You would have hard time using non-OO stuff. It can get used to and, to be honest, can be quite rewarding since You can do a lot with it. If you picked OpenGL than you would get all the 3D transformations for free, but still have to transform from spherical coordinate system to cartesian by yourself (first wiki article still helpful). After that it's just a matter of using some text drawing class, such as `TextRenderer` that comes with JOGL distribution.

So OpenGL helps You with view projection calculations and is hardware accelerated. The Java2D would require more math to use, but in my opinion, this approach seems a bit easier. Oh, and by the way - the Java2D tries to use any graphic acceleration there is (OpenGL or DirectDraw) internally. So You are shielded from certain low-level problems.

For both options You need also to bind mouse coordinates s to rotational speed of sphere. Whether it's Java2D or OpenGL the code will look very similar. Just map mouse coordinates related to the center of panel to some speed vector. At the drawing time You could use the vector to rotate the sphere accordingly.

And one more thing: if You would want to try OpenGL I'd recommend: [Processing language](http://processing.org/) created on MIT especially for rich graphic applets. Their 3D API, not so coincidentally, is almost the same as OpenGL, but without much of the cruft. So if You want the quickest *prototype* that's the best bet. Consult [this discussion thread](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1214504959) for actual example. Note: Processing is written in Java.

Comment: Thank you for detailed and helpful answer! Sorry, I haven't sufficient reputation for voting up :(
The Java2D solution would fit but I need the text to be clickable.
Could you tell me please, does JOGL provide some mechanism allows to listen the clicks on rendered text? If so - I'll start on a journey...

Comment: Yes, there is a special facility - OpenGL picking (consult http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/ ). It works that You set a name on particular object and then use special rendering mode to indentify it. It can get quite messy, because it's very low level, but I did it few times so can be of help if needed.

Answer (score 3):

That's not really 3D. There are no perspective transformations or mapping the text on some 3D shape (such as, say, a sphere). What you have is a bunch of strings where each string has an associated depth (or Z order). Strings "closer" to you are painted with a stronger shade of gray and larger font size.

The motion of each string as you move the mouse is indeed a 3D shape which looks like a slanted circle around a fixed center - with the slant depending on where the mouse cursor is. That's simple math - if you figure it for one string, you figure it out for all. And then the last piece would be to scatter the strings so that they don't overlap too much, and give each one the initial weight based on their frequency.

That's what [most of the code](http://svn.wp-plugins.org/wp-cumulus/trunk/flash%20sources/com/roytanck/wpcumulus/TagCloud.as) is doing. So you need to either do the math, or translate the ActionScript to Java2D blindly. And no, there is no need for JOGL.

Comment: +1 Mathematically yours answer seems to have a solid base. Will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just [download](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-cumulus.1.23.zip) the source code, and have a look? Even if you can't write PHP, it should still be possible to read it and figure out how the algorithm works.

Comment: I'll do it if there isn't less painful way :) Like Java source.
BTW, what rendering technique could you suggest - JPanel/JLabel or may be OpenGL or smth. else?

Comment: It's a Flash movie, the source is in ActionScript - not PHP.